# What is the highest-rated unedited question on a site?

Tags: discussion, statistics

What question, which has never been edited (even by its author) outside of the 5-minute grace period, has the highest score on a specific site, for example Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Stack Overflow That must be [When to use margin vs padding in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452)

based on this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/860146):

```sql
select top 1
       id as [Post Link]
from posts p
where p.posttypeid = 1 -- Questions 
and not exists (select * 
                from posthistory ph
                where ph.postid = p.id
                and ph.posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6,7,8,9)) -- edit and rollback events
order by score desc
```

or if you are an `left outer join` lover

```sql
select top 1
       p.id as [Post Link]
from posts p
left outer join 
     posthistory ph on ph.postid = p.id
                   and ph.posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6,7,8,9)
where p.posttypeid = 1
and ph.id is null 
order by score desc
```

You can switch in SEDE to different sites to run the query against their posts.

If you like to have a go at writing SEDE queries yourself, do try the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

While maybe less relevant for this question, keep in mind SEDE only gets refreshed once a week, on Sunday.